# How to get dynamic ip in xml file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml

I have 'links.xml' file it contains url's which is used to perform instant search and go for the particular page specified by the url.

'links.xml' source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<pages>

<link>
<title>Advanced</title>
<url>http://{192.168.44.128}/reboot.php</url>
</link>

<link>
<title>Manager</title>
<url>http://{192.168.44.128}/manager.php</url>
</link>

<link>
<title>Firmware</title>
<url>http://{192.168.44.128}/system.php</url>
</link>

<link>
<title>States</title>
<url>http://{192.168.44.128}/states.php</url>
</link>
</pages>
```

In above code: {192.168.44.128}=192.168.44.128
(I couldn't post the question without the braces.)

I want to send dynamic IP address in the url tag because IP address keeps changing and its not static IP. Along with this file I have used a php and a html file. So can dynamic address be provided in xml file only without making any changes to other files? If yes, then how? If not, then how to send dynamic IP address in the url tag.

This code is taken from:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp

Regards.

Comment: You can use `<?php $ipAddr = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>`

Comment: @prava Should I use <?php $ipAddr = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?> in links.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MIME types to change the output.
Just create a php file and use it to display dynamic ip adresses.
Use `header('Content-type: application/xml');` to send it as XML.

However if you use it to display raw xml data use `text/xml` instead of `application/xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing in your PHP file. Please check below if it works for you:

```
<?php 
$file = "links.xml";

//load xml object
$xml= simplexml_load_file($file);

$ipAddr = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

// here you can use loop to get all the file name
$xml->pages->link->url = 'http://' . $ipAddr . '/file.php';

//store the value into the file
file_put_contents($file, $xml->asXML());
?>
```