# How to get host server IP address in xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Following is the xml file:

links.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<pages>

<link>
<title>Advanced</title>
<url>http://{192.168.44.128}/advanced.php</url>
</link>

</pages>
```

In the above code {192.168.44.128}=192.168.44.128

In the place of 192.168.44.128 I want to replace it with current IP address of the server. The IP address of the server is dynamic, so the above code only works for one IP ie. 192.168.44.128. Therefore how to get host server IP address in xml file and use it in the url tag as shown above?

If this is not possible please suggest me an answer how to get the server IP address and use it in the url tag instead of directly entering the IP address in the url tag.

Comment: have you tried using `$_SERVER` variables, like: `<url><?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?></url>`

Comment: i tried this: <url>http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>/advanced.php</url> . But in the browser the link 'http://192.168.44.128/advanced.php' is not created instead the link is 'http:///'. If the url tag is <url>http://192.168.44.128/advanced.php</url> then the browser opens 'advanced.php' page. I changed the file name from 'links.xml' to 'links.php' as well.

Comment: Self-Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24971920/367456

Comment: If you've got problems with code from w3schools, please contact the author on w3schools who has written that code and ask your clarification questions to her/him. We can not provide support for the code-examples on that website. See as well: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

In normal Apache-setups files with the XML-extensions don't get parsed by PHP (and I suggests to leave it that way). You can create a PHP-file (for example `links-xml.php`) wich dynamicaly creates the XML-data:

```
<?php
// Set up the header, so the browser knows it's an XML-file
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy -->
<pages>

<link>
<title>Advanced</title>
<url>http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] ?>/advanced.php</url>
</link>

</pages>
```

Comment: I am getting this error- Warning: DOMDocument::load(): XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document. Should I put the php code after'</pages>'?

Comment: I guess there is more whitespace between `?>` and `<?xml` then there should be (a single enter should be ignored, but spaces etc. are deadly). Change it in (`?><?xml version...`) to be sure.

Comment: I changed it to:    <?php
// Set up the header, so the browser knows it's an XML-file
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>... But still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you temporarly change `'text/xml'` to `'text/plain'` to check what your server sends to your browser?

Comment: @user3799981 this is already correct, remove the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` should be working fine